# URL schema to get users and playlists a Beats Music user is following

Tags: beatsmusic

We have our access_token and various GETs work fine, etc.

However, when we try to to get a list of items that the currently logged in user follows, the server responds with a user not found error.

To be clear, the URL:

```
https://partner.api.beatsmusic.com/v1/api/users/249651278634942464/follows?access_token=...&client_id=...&user_context=249651278634942464
```

returns:

```
{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"User: not found."}.
```

Yet this URL returns valid results:
    https://partner.api.beatsmusic.com/v1/api/users/249651278634942464/mymusic/tracks?access_token=...&client_id=...&user_context=249651278634942464

So what's the right way to form the URL to get the assets the logged in user follows?  I've been over the web API docs a million times and it the first URL is what it seems to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve follows for a users, you just need the user ID and access token only. You do have the option to use the filters on the docs.

Example: 
https://partner.api.beatsmusic.com/v1/api/users/ID/follows?access_token=....

*Note: Setting a limit is optional, but if the user follows higher than 200 assets, you will only receive the maximum of 200 using the API.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my initial post.  What you cited from the beats API docs is querying if a given user follows another given user.  What we're looking for is the API query that returns the list of artists a given (or current) user follows.  For example, in beats app or on beatsmusic.com, one can follow an artist, but that's different than explicitly adding the artist to your library.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no way to query for the list of artists a given user follows (vs in their library).  If it's the case that this query isn't available, is there a way to get a list of tracks sorted by date for all the artists a given user is following.  Otherwise, please describe the purpose/role of following an artist vs adding it one's library.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Following an artist will alert you to news or releases about the artist. Adding the tracks or albums to your library or playlists will allow you to make content available for offline listening and save the music in a separate interface.

Comment: Is there any update on this?

The goal is to have an API query that allows our app to fetch the tracks/artists (assets) the current user is following.  See what I mean?

Comment: You can apply these filters for follows: users, genre, artists. Users can follow other users, but for artists alone, you filter using just artists:
filters=type:artist
This will not include tracks because tracks can only be rated. Users can subscribe to and rate playlists.

Comment: Update: this issue is still unresolved.  To be clear: I'm aware of the API docs and please see that the goal is to get a list of assets followed by the user, *not* see if a specific asset is followed by the user.  All the stuff you've been pointing to in this discussion is in the docs and regards to the latter.